# Trying to alter a column but iit is showing error saying invalid alter option

Tags: database, mysql

I am trying to change the data type of a particular column by using SQL query

```
ALTER TABLE employee
ALTER COLUMN Join_Date date;
```

with this it is showing error saying invalid alter option

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you should use `MODIFY` to update your column type:

```
ALTER TABLE employee
MODIFY Join_Date date;
```

You can read about MODIFY statement in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot.i am also trying to execte the same query in postgres .But is there an option to change the datatype in postgres as well